# windows store app always crash in other remote devices

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-component

I am developing a windows store app, it works perfect in my own pc by local machine mode, and it works in my co-work's pc by remote marchine too.

However, it doesn't work in other people's pc.

it's always thrown an exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException, a specific module is not found.

it seems not recognize some of dll, but it works good in our machines.

why do our machines work ?

what should I do now ? Has anyone in this situation before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved.

was a mistake that link a dll which from visual studio to our winrt library.

so it never works on other devices which has not install visual studio.